# How to prevent UI flicker/load while making async call from Angular to Web API?

Tags: angular, webapi

In UI,i need to show the updated messages from the API, I am setting time interval  to get the messages from API, in every 5 seconds async method is being called to load if any new message is available.
Every time when it's making Async call from Angular to Web API, i can see flickering/loading for 2 seconds on the screen.
Here is the code,

notification.html file

```
  <div class="numberCircle" style="cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="notificationcount >0"
            > {{notificationcount}}</div> 

  <h6 *ngFor="let msg of notificationmsgs"><span class="badge badge-success">{{msg}}</span></h6>
```

notification.ts file

```
 ngOnInit(){
   // this.getNotificationMessage();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getNotificationMessage();
    },5000)
    
  }

  async getNotificationMessage() {      
      await this.notificationservice.getNotificationMessages().subscribe(  
        (messages: NotificationResult) => {              
          this.notificationmsgs = messages.data; 
          this.notificationcount = messages.recordscount                                    
        },  
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error         
      );        
    }
```

notificationservice.ts file

```
 getNotificationMessages():Observable<any> {  
    const baseurl = `${this.apiurl}api/Notification/notificationDetails`;    
    return this.http.get<any>(baseurl)  
      .pipe(  
        catchError(this.handleError)  
      );  
  }
```

It should load the data in background. I don't want it to show any loading/flickering effect on UI,while making Async call.

Please help me out to do this, Or please suggest if there is any other way to achieve the requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If notifications have a unique property (such as `id`), I'd suggest to start with a tracking function in the `*ngFor` loop:

```
<h6 *ngFor="let msg of notificationmsgs; trackBy: msgTrackFn"> ... </h6>
```

in TypeScript add something like this to your component:

```
msgTrackFn(index: number, msg: Message){
  return msg.id
}
```

The tracking function will allow angular to figure out which DOM elements require re-rendering. This should reduce the flicker by a lot.

---

#### Edit

to improve OP-included code

I'd suggest that you simplify the code. You're unnecessarily mixing Promises and Observables. The polling technique can be done in a much simpler way:

```
interval(5000).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.notificationservice.getNotificationMessages()).pipe(
    catchError(error => of(undefined)),
    // tuck catchError here to prevent http errors
    // from killing the stream
  ),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$), // for unsubscribing
).subscribe({
  next: (messages: NotificationResult) => {              
    this.notificationmsgs = messages.data; 
    this.notificationcount = messages.recordscount                                  
  },  
  error: error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, 
});
```

and that's it. No `setInterval`s, no `await`s. Clean and simple.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but i am still finding that page is flickering, in every 5 second if application shows flicker/loading, it doesn't look good. here in this requirement, i want to load the data in background without any flicker effect on screen.

Comment: It has happened to me quite many times that the flicker actually signified a complete page reload for some unwanted reason. Make sure it is not the case.